# How to download a large file using google-api-java-client on Android?

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

Recently, I try to use google-api-java-client library to access google document. I can use this library to get a list, create new documents, and update successfully. However, when I want to download a large file (> 10mb) from Google Document, it causes OutOfMemoryError.

```
03-30 17:57:10.650: E/AndroidRuntime(11022): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-30 17:57:10.650: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
03-30 17:57:10.650: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
03-30 17:57:10.650: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):    at com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent.copy(AbstractInputStreamContent.java:213)
03-30 17:57:10.650: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):    at com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent.copy(AbstractInputStreamContent.java:179)
03-30 17:57:10.650: E/AndroidRuntime(11022):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.getContent(HttpResponse.java:384)
```

This is my code:

```
try {
    ...
    HttpRequest request = getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(link);
    HttpResponse response = request.execute();
    InputStream is = response.getContent();
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The response code is 200, and it can work successfully on small files.
Is there any method to download a large file using google-api-java-client?

Comment: I think that what you do in your code where the three dots are now, is the relevant part. If the file is too big, you must stream it to the filesystem because you cannot hold it in memory.

Comment: I find that the problem is the api function response.getContent(), which uses ByteArrayOutputStream to save the file data. So when the file is too large, it will cause OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the problem!  Looks like a bug to me.  Filed it here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/issues/detail?id=82

As a work-around, please disable logging for this request as follows:

```
request.setContentLoggingLimit(0);
```